# Poincaré inequality for a subspace of $H^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Suppose that $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is a smooth, bounded, and connected domain. Let \begin{equation}
H=\{u\in H^2(\Omega):\int_\Omega u(x) dx=0 ~\text{and}~ \nabla u\cdot v=0~ \text{on}~\partial\Omega\}.
\end{equation} Show that $H$ is a Hilbert space, and prove that there exists $C>0$ such that for any $u\in H$, 
\begin{equation}
||u||_{H^1(\Omega)}\le C\sum_{|\alpha|=2} ||D^\alpha u||_{L^2(\Omega)}.
\end{equation}

I can prove the space is a Hilbert space. How do I put my hands on the inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that the inequality doesn't hold, so for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there exists a $u_n\in H$ such that
$$
\|u_n\|_{H^1}>n\sum_{|\alpha|=2}\|D^\alpha u_n\|_{L^2}.
$$
Further, normalizing, we can assume that $\|u_n\|_{H^1}=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So,
$$
\frac{1}{n}>\sum_{|\alpha|=2}\|D^\alpha u_n\|_{L^2}
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. You should be able to derive a contradiction from here by taking a convergent subsequence of $(u_n)$ in $L^2$ and using the fact that $\int_\Omega u(x)dx=0$ for all $u\in H$.