# Poincaré inequality for $H^2(\Omega)$-functions

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I am wondering if given a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with Lipschitz boundary, then there exists $C>0$ such that, for every $u\in H^2(\Omega)$,
$$
\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\le C \left(\|D^2u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}+\|u\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}\right).
$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have an example that shows that the $\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}$ term is necessary?

Comment: I thought the third term was taking care of constants and the second one of linear polynomials

Comment: But as far as I can tell the third term also takes care of the linear polynomials, right?

Comment: Yes. I got confused reading this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/727833/poincaré-inequality-for-a-subspace-of-h2-omega?rq=1. Then, do you think the inequality holds?

Comment: I am fairly sure it is true.  I don't however know a good reference or a simple proof.  For example, I believe one can extend $u$ to an $H^2$ function with compact support in a ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and then use a Poincare inequality in the ball.  The extension however is not easy.  A more direct proof would use the fundamental theorem of calculus on many segments in the domain, but then there you have to do potentially complicated geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the inequality
$$
\|u\|_{H^1} \le C (\|D^2u\|_{L^2} + \|u\|_{L^2}) \ \forall u\in H^2
$$
has to be proven, as the first-order terms are the only terms of the $H^2$ norm that are missing on the right-hand side.

You can argue by contradiction: assume there is no such $C$, then there is a sequence $(u_k)$ such that
$$
\|u_k\|_{H^1} > k (\|D^2u_k\|_{L^2} + \|u_k\|_{L^2}).
$$
Obviously, we can choose $u_k$ such that $\|u_k\|_{H^1}=1$. 
Then the inequality above implies that $(u_k)$ is bounded in $H^2$.
Then after extracting a subsequence, $u_k\rightharpoonup u$ in $H^2$ and $u_k\to u$ in $H^1$ (by compact embeddings).

Since $\|u_k\|_{L^2}\to 0$ by the construction of $u_k$, it follows $u=0$.
This is a contradiction to $u_k\to u$ in $H^1$ and $\|u_k\|_{H^1}=1$.