# Poincare inequality in Sobolev space without zero boundary value

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, sobolev-spaces

Let
$$
X=\{u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}|u|^{q-2}u\,dx=0\},
$$
where $1<p<N$ and $1<q<p^{*}=\frac{Np}{N-p}$. Here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain.

Here $X$ is endowded with the norm
$$
\|u\|=\|u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}+\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}.
$$
My question is it possible to say that
$$
\|u\|_1=\|\nabla u\|_{L^p(\Omega)}
$$
is an equivalent norm on $X$? I hope if this is true, the some version of Poincare inequality might help which I am unaware. Kindly help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the usual proof by contradiction?

Comment: Thanks. Contradiction to which statement?

Comment: I tried the contradictory argument as in Poincare for average, but could not succeed.

Comment: Also do you think it is true?

Comment: I found an argument in the livk: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193253/equaivalent-norm-on-sobolev-space?rq=1  But it is unclear to me how $u$ become constant using that $\|\nabla u_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\to 0$ there in the argument of the last answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also, for I thought the argument on page 23-24 of the link: http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1016/j.anihpc.2011.08.001.pdf might help. But I could not get the first inequality involving $u$ on page 24 there. Kindly help.